# Setting a flyout to a button

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I just wanted to learning something; 
specially - trying to create a flyout, set it to a button and finally show that flyout.

Here is my code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (FirstNameBox.Text == "" || SecondNameBox.Text == "" || AvatarButton.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        Flyout flyout = new Flyout();
        var txtblock = new TextBlock();
        txtblock.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        txtblock.Text = "You haven't set something.";

        flyout.Placement = FlyoutPlacementMode.Top;
        flyout.Content = txtblock;

        FlyoutBase.SetAttachedFlyout(button, flyout);

        button.Flyout.ShowAt(button);
    }
```

The error what was throwed is that my button called "button" hasnt any flyout, but i just attached it before "show" :C

Do anyone know what's going on ?

Comment: If I could offer any advice at all it would be to learn to do it in XAML. When you start learning MVVM, data binding, command binding etc, you'll have one thing less to learn. Also, if you build things in behind code it makes things INFINITELY more complex

Comment: Thanks, i will do it firstly as u are telling. But in this code; would you like to show me the correct way?

Comment: I couldn't begin to speculate on why it isn't working without actually compiling the code and seeing all of it working. It could be anything.

Comment: Here's an example of how to do it in XAML. As you can see it's way less complex https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.button.flyout

Comment: Generally follow Anthony's comments. As for showing flyout from code, instead of attaching it, just show it with `flyout.ShowAt(button);`, should work.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, idk why.. i went otherside, created that flyout for menu, and I am catching event "Opening"; In function `Flyout_Opening(object sender, object e)` i added `if (error())
                (sender as Flyout).Hide();` Ant it desnt work, Flyout don't want to close ;X Why is so hard to provide close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in this line:

```
button.Flyout.ShowAt(button);
```

Try writing this:

```
flyout.ShowAt(button);
```